# How to make each select option have their own checkboxes and make the select dropdown to where I can select multiple options

Tags: html

The problem I am having is that I want each of the `select` dropdowns to have checkboxes beside each `option` and I want to select multiple options from each of the `select` dropdowns. I want this for each variable that has `select` dropdown below. Can someone help me with this? In case you don't know, the for loops pull in info from other pages that I am creating.

#### HTML Code:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">


<form>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>ChapterName</label>
      <input type="text" name="chaptername" class="form-control" value="{{ story.chaptername }}" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Type of Chapter</label>
      <select id="11" name="chaptertype" class="form-control" required>
        <option>Select one</option>
        <option>Original</option>
        <option>Crossover</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Battle/Story Mode</label>
      <select id="BM" name="battleandorstorymode" class="form-control" required>
        <option>Select one</option>
        <option>Cross Active Battle System</option>
        <option>Hack-and-Slash System</option>
        <option>Turn-Based system</option>
        {% for x in battleandorstorymodes %}
        <option value="{{x.battleandorstorymode}}">{{x.battleandorstorymode}}</option>
        {% endfor %}
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Boss ID</label>
      <!--<select id="b" name="locationid" class="form-control" required>-->
      <select id="BI" name="bossid" class="form-control" required>
        <option>Select one</option>

        {% for x in bosses %}
        <option value="{{x.bossid}}">{{x.bossname}}</option>
        {% endfor %}
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Item ID</label>

      <select id="II" name="itemid" class="form-control" required>
        <option>Select one</option>
        {% for x in items %}
        <option value="{{x.itemid}}">{{x.itemname}}</option>
        {% endfor %}
      </select>

    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Location ID</label>
      <select id="LI" name="locationid" class="form-control" required>
        <option>Select one</option>
        {% for x in locations %}
        <option value="{{x.locationid}}">{{x.locationname}}</option>
        {% endfor %}
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Monster ID</label>
      <select id="OM" name="monsterid" class="form-control" required>
        <option>Select one</option>
        {% for x in allenemies %}
        <option value="{{x.monsterid}}">{{x.monstername}}</option>
        {% endfor %}
      </select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group dynamic-block" id="tt" style="display: none">
      <label>Events</label>
      <textarea name="events" class="form-control" style="color: black">{{ story.events }}</textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group dynamic-block" id="vv" style="display: none">
      <label> Link</label>
      <input type="text" name="link" class="form-control" value="{{ story.link }}" required>
    </div>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary angelus">Create</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: what is `{{ story.chaptername }}` ? Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). To get the best answers to your question we like to see that you've attempted to solve the problem yourself first using a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Here's a [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) you might find useful...

Answer (score 0):

You want to implement a multiselect dropwon. That's impossible with `select` and `option`. Instead you will need to generate your own control, like:

```js
function openclose(id) {
    let element = document.getElementById('myselect');
    if (element.className.indexOf('invisible') >= 0) element.classList.remove('invisible');
    else element.classList.add('invisible');
}
```

```css
.invisible {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="open me" onclick="openclose('myselect')">
<div class="invisible" id="myselect">
    <p><label>option1 <input type="checkbox"></label></p>
    <p><label>option2 <input type="checkbox"></label></p>
    <p><label>option3 <input type="checkbox"></label></p>
    <p><label>option4 <input type="checkbox"></label></p>
</div>
```

The control above does not handle blur event, because it's only a proof-of-concept. You can easily implement the blur event and you can also create a function that generates this kind of control and adds it into a context. But most importantly, you need to accept the fact that this will not be achieved via `select` and `option`.